# Partition comparison between source and target

Tags: python, mysql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have to do partition comparison between source and target. Source will be MySql, Teradata and target will be snowflake, GCP. I am not sure from where to start. Please suggest what all steps are required for partition check. i am doing comparison in python.

Example- In mysql we have table A and in snowflake we have same table A. Now we need to do partition check.

please suggest what all checks we can do for partition and how.

Comment: What is a "Partition check" or "Partition comparison"? What does that mean?

Comment: Partition comparison mean between two databases partition defined on columns and compare.

Comment: traditional way is suppose partition defined on date column and we can query where date between 1st jan 2020 to 31st dec 2022 and thn compare. how we can check/compare partition data between two DB's.

Comment: I would think you would need to pull Table DDL from all three platforms and compare how they were defined. It's sort of an apples vs oranges comparison though as these three RDBMS products are vastly different from eachother. I know you can specify a cluster on Snowflake, but it's my understanding that micro-partitioning is performed automatically on insert on that platform, so.. how would you even compare? I'm not sure you can or that it would make much of a difference given how vastly different the architecture is there compared to Teradata or mysql.

Comment: On Snowflake, micro-partitioning is done automatically - there is no range partitioning as you might see in other popular RDBMS platforms.  That said, if you are defining queries to run on your source system to count rows, count nulls, aggregate select columns (avg / sum) or get min/max values, those queries should also run on Snowflake and you can compare those results.  Just use the range partition in your query criteria (e.g. WHERE Date between <start> and <end>).